# Flatten a bunch of key/value dictionaries into a single dictionary?

Tags: python

I want to convert this: `[{u'Key': 'color', u'Value': 'red'}, {u'Key': 'size', u'Value': 'large'}]` into this: `{'color': 'red', 'size': 'large'}`.

Anyone have any recommendations?  I'm been playing with list comprehensions, lambda functions, and `zip()` for over an hour and feel like I'm missing an obvious solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and try something like this:

#### Python-2.7 or Python-3.x

```
>>> a = [{u'Key': 'color', u'Value': 'red'}, {u'Key': 'size', u'Value': 'large'}]
>>> b = {i['Key']:i['Value'] for i in a}
>>> b
{'color': 'red', 'size': 'large'}
```

#### Python-2.6

```
b = dict((i['Key'], i['Value']) for i in a)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that this is Python 3?  If so, I apologize for not specifying that I'm using 2.7.

Comment: Ah, yes... works on 2.7 but not 2.6.  (I'm using two systems here).  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use dict comprehension.

```
>>> l = [{u'Key': 'color', u'Value': 'red'}, {u'Key': 'size', u'Value': 'large'}]
>>> {i['Key']:i['Value'] for i in l}
{'color': 'red', 'size': 'large'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Lambda functions.

```
a={}
dic = [{u'Key': 'color', u'Value': 'red'}, {u'Key': 'size', u'Value': 'large'}]
reduce(lambda x,y:a.__setitem__(y["Key"],y["Value"]),dic,a)
```

OP

```
print a
{'color': 'red', 'size': 'large'}
```

As suggested:

```
import operator
reduce(lambda x,y:operator.setitem(a,y["Key"],y["Value"]),dic,a)
```

Comment: Instead of calling `a.__setitem__`, you could also use [`operator.setitem`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.setitem).